# loop a function a random number of times in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a script to generate random sentences from words and phrases in an array. This works.

I want to make a paragraph from these random sentences. What I have done though is repeating the same sentence, rather than running the function again and again to create new sentences.

I think my error is in this part of the code.

```
const randParagraph = (len, end, words, wordLen) =>
[...Array(len)].map(() =>  addCommaAfter(fullSentWithEnd,sentLength(5,12)))
.join(' ') + (end || ' ');
```

fullSentWithEnd is the final function in generating the sentences.

```
const fullSentWithEnd = randSentence(ipsumText, sentLength(5,12), '.')
```

and addAfterComma is splitting the sentence to add a comma.

```
const addCommaAfter = (sentence, index) => {
word_split = sentence.split(" ");
word_split[index] = word_split[index]+",";
word_split[0] = word_split[0][0].toUpperCase() + word_split[0].slice(1);
return word_split.join(" ");
```

}

I thought in randParagraph the new array was saying run addCommaAfter and pass in fullSentWithEnd, and tell it to run a random number of times between 5 and 12. But now I am wondering if it is actually saying that, or if that is what is telling it to repeat the same result.

Would love some thoughts.

```js
const ipsumText = ["adventure", "endless youth", "dust", "iconic landmark", "spontaneous", "carefree", "selvedge","on the road", "open road", "stay true", "free spirit", "urban", "live on the edge", "the true wanderer", "vintage motorcyle", "american lifestyle", "epic landscape", "low slung denim", "naturaL"];

const randInt = (lower, upper) => 
Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper-lower)) + lower

const randWord = (words) => words[randInt(0, words.length)]

const randSentence = (words, len, end) => 
[...Array(len)].map(() => randWord(words)).join(' ') + (end || ' ')

const randWordWithEnd = (end) => randWord(ipsumText) + end 
const randWordWithFullStop = randWordWithEnd('. ') 
const randWordWithComma = randWordWithEnd(', ')

const sentLength = (min,max) => {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;};

const fullSentWithEnd = randSentence(ipsumText, sentLength(5,12), '.') 
const fullSentNoEnd = randSentence(ipsumText, sentLength(5,12)) 
const fullSentComposed = fullSentNoEnd + randWordWithFullStop

const addCommaAfter = (sentence, index) => {
 word_split = sentence.split(" ");
 word_split[index] = word_split[index]+",";
 word_split[0] = word_split[0][0].toUpperCase() + word_split[0].slice(1);
 return word_split.join(" ");
}

console.log(fullSentWithEnd) 
console.log(" ");
console.log(addCommaAfter(fullSentWithEnd,sentLength(3,8))); 

const randParagraph = (len, end, words, wordLen) =>
[...Array(len)].map(() => addCommaAfter(fullSentWithEnd,sentLength(5,12)))
.join(' ') + (end || ' ');

console.log(randParagraph(sentLength(5,8), '', ipsumText, sentLength(5,12)));
```

Comment: can you give code that can be run?

Comment: just added a snippet above @SufianSaory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are seeding the **addCommaAfter** func from **randParagraph** func **with same sentence**. instead change the seeding with random sentences like following, it will create paragraph with random sentences.

```
const randParagraph = (len, end, words, wordLen) =>
    [...Array(len)].map(() => addCommaAfter(randSentence(words, sentLength(5, 12), '.'), sentLength(5, 12)))
        .join(' ') + (end || ' ');
```

**Full code:**

```js
const ipsumText = ["adventure", "endless youth", "dust", "iconic landmark", "spontaneous", "carefree", "selvedge", "on the road", "open road", "stay true", "free spirit", "urban", "live on the edge", "the true wanderer", "vintage motorcyle", "american lifestyle", "epic landscape", "low slung denim", "naturaL"];

const randInt = (lower, upper) =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower)) + lower

const randWord = (words) => words[randInt(0, words.length)]

const randSentence = (words, len, end) =>
    [...Array(len)].map(() => randWord(words)).join(' ') + (end || ' ')

const randWordWithEnd = (end) => randWord(ipsumText) + end
const randWordWithFullStop = randWordWithEnd('. ')
const randWordWithComma = randWordWithEnd(', ')

const sentLength = (min, max) => { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; };

const fullSentWithEnd = randSentence(ipsumText, sentLength(5, 12), '.')
const fullSentNoEnd = randSentence(ipsumText, sentLength(5, 12))
const fullSentComposed = fullSentNoEnd + randWordWithFullStop

const addCommaAfter = (sentence, index) => {
    word_split = sentence.split(" ");
    if (index >= word_split.length) {
        index = word_split.length - 1;
    }
    word_split[index] = word_split[index] + ",";
    word_split[0] = word_split[0][0].toUpperCase() + word_split[0].slice(1);
    return word_split.join(" ");
}

console.log(fullSentWithEnd)
console.log(" ");
console.log(addCommaAfter(fullSentWithEnd, sentLength(3, 8)));

const randParagraph = (len, end, words, wordLen) =>
    [...Array(len)].map(() => addCommaAfter(randSentence(words, sentLength(5, 12), '.'), sentLength(5, 12)))
        .join(' ') + (end || ' ');

console.log(randParagraph(sentLength(5, 8), '', ipsumText, sentLength(5, 12)));
```

Comment: right, I can see that now @sufian. Thanks. There a few "undefined" coming up. Would that just be because a parameter has nothing passed in to it.

Comment: yes, due to out of index issue in addCommaAfter function undefined was coming. now corrected.@garrethwills

Comment: I can see you added the if statement, so that if the random integer determining the length of the split was longer than the sentence, it becomes  one less than the sentence length. Great,

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what exactly your code does, but I've got this little framework for generating random texts:

```js
ucfirst = s => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);

rand = (min, max) => min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));

sample = a => a[rand(0, a.length)];

times = (n, fn) => [...Array(n)].map(fn);

seq = (min, max, fn, sep) => times(rand(min, max), fn).join(sep);

// this will use random "words"

char = () => sample("abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuwvxyz");
word = seq(1, 10, char, '');

// this will use an array of predefined words

words = [
    'the', 'be', 'to', 'of', 'and', 'a', 'in', 'that', 'have', 'I', 'it', 'for', 'not', 'on', 'with', 'he', 'as', 'you', 'do',
    'at', 'this', 'but', 'his', 'by', 'from', 'they', 'we', 'say', 'her', 'she', 'or', 'an', 'will', 'my', 'one', 'all',
    'would', 'there', 'their', 'what', 'so', 'up', 'out', 'if', 'about', 'who', 'get', 'which', 'go', 'me', 'when', 'make',
    'can', 'like', 'time', 'no', 'just', 'him', 'know', 'take', 'person', 'into', 'year', 'your', 'good', 'some', 'could',
    'them', 'see', 'other', 'than', 'then', 'now', 'look', 'only', 'come', 'its', 'over', 'think', 'also', 'back', 'after',
    'use', 'two', 'how', 'our', 'work', 'first', 'well', 'way', 'even', 'new', 'want', 'because', 'any', 'these', 'give',
    'day', 'most', 'us'];

word = () => sample(words)

phrase = () => seq(3, 10, word, ' ');

sent = () => seq(1, 10, phrase, ', ');

sentence = () => ucfirst(sent()) + sample('.?!');

paragraph = () => seq(1, 10, sentence, ' ');

text = () => seq(2, 20, paragraph, '\n\n');

console.log(text())
```

Comment: my code creates sentences out of an assortment of phrases and words I have stored in an array. The idea is to generate ipsum text that has a flavour or suits a theme. Your code creates its own words from what I can see, using the letters of the alphabet randomly. My problem though is I haven't managed to get the sentences to be random through the paragraph. They repeat.

Comment: Just replace `word` in the above code with your own implementation (e.g. `sample(array-of-words)`.

Comment: sorry @georg I don't follow. I'm still new at this. I'm not sure how you're suggesting I add it. I tried changing it for my array, but obviously didn't get it right

Comment: well, that is a much neater way to achieve a similar result. I'm looking through what you've done to understand it. Thanks for sharing. The only difference I see is that you have very few full stops. I'm looking to see how I would change that.